# What's the best way to upload 10,000 folders to a Google Nearline bucket when no folder option given?

Tags: windows

I have 1MM+ photos in 10,000 folders on a Windows PC I need to put into a Nearline bucket.  Google's documentation shows that in the Developer Console there is an upload folder option, which does not appear in my Developer Console, nor can you drag and drop folders, which also is supposed to be possible through the Developer Console. Of course moving a million photos manually is not practical.  What would be the simplest way to automate the movement?  I have not tried yet installing the python command line utility gsutil yet to try a copy command, but can it handle that many files?